# Select a node with a certain text value using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, hyperlink, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

So I'm aware of how to select a node using htmlagilitypack:

```
HtmlNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='description']")
```

etc... but say I have a site set up in the following way:

```
<a href="/link1/">This is Link 1</a>
<a href="/link2/">This is information i want to get to</a>
<a href="/link3/">This is Link 3</a>
<a href="/link4/">This is information i want to get to</a>
<a href="/link5/">This is Link 5</a>
<a href="/link6/">This is Link 6</a>
```

etc...

Now, the snippet is short, but basically, The links are asymmetric, and I only want to access links that have the text value

> "this is information i want to get to"

(I'm not familiar enough with hmtl to use proper terminology here, sorry). Is there a method in htmlagilitypack where I can check this text value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the `text()` function:

```
SelectNodes("a[text()='This is information i want to get to']")
```